# How to access a SwiftUI view from its parent UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am using a SwiftUI view from a UIViewController using UIHostingController.

This is not working:

```swift
viewController.contentView.first as? SwiftUIView
```

Because it's not a SwiftUI view anymore, but a UIView.

Is it possible to get back the SwiftUI view from the UIViewController?

Comment: You can use the `rootView` property of your UIHostingController, but it probably isn't the best approach to try and access the SwiftUI view directly; you would typically access the view model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the reference on a view controller's variable to the SwiftUI view when you create it.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  // Store the reference to the SwiftUI view after creating it.
  var swiftUiView: SwiftUiView?
  // ...
}
```